# 400 Bad Request With CSS .htaccess rule

Tags: zend-framework, .htaccess

I'm trying to whitelabel the Zend framework, so I've created folder in application called Site.

This url: http://local.branch.test.com/site-css/1/layout.css returns a 400 Bad Request.

With the following rule:

```
 RewriteRule ^site-css/([0-9]+)/(.*)$    ../application/site/$1/design/css/$2 [L]
```

Full .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule !\.(js|ico|gif|jpg|png|css)$ /index.php

RewriteRule ^site-css/([0-9]+)/(.*)$     ../application/site/$1/design/css/$2 [L]
```

Ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is caused by apache being set up to point to /public. The project doesn't have access to read files outside of its root.

Therefore I have moved site into public.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^site-css/([0-9]+)/(.*)$     ../application/site/$1/design/css/$2 [L]
```

Comment: Doesnt work, apache log says:

[Thu Jul 22 14:15:06 2010] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] Invalid URI in request GET /site-css/1/layout.css? HTTP/1.1